# На какое событие подписаться, чтобы уловить момент скачивания видео html5?

Tags: javascript, html5, видео

На какое событие подписаться, чтобы уловить момент скачивания видео html5 с плеера или как добраться до кнопки скачать видео и повести на нее обработчик onClick?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный плеер не генерирует событий. Более того, стандартные плееры не всех браузеров в принципе позволяют скачивать видео.

Comment: а как поймать это событие. мне нужно при скачивании видео выполнить свою функцию

Comment: @werty, Поймать его никак нельзя, по тому что его нет. То что вам нужно - этого создать или подключить HTML5 плеер. Посмотрите в сторону [MediaElement.js](http://www.mediaelementjs.com).

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте как на любом плеере на видео хостинге, а именно у тега `<video>` уберите стандартную панель управление (убрать атрибут `controls`) и напишите свою на js и там добавьте кнопку скачивания. В интернете есть готовые решения, можно поискать.